# Ubuntu 20.02 LTS Desktop for aarch64

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, mac, apple

Is there a desktop version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS available for aarch64 processors?  I have an Apple M1 and I need to have 20.04 LTS with a desktop and ROS Noetic installed for a robotics class.  I don't have the option for using other versions because prewritten scripts for the class are designed for these version.

I see that there is a ubuntu 20.04 base for arm64 available, but I don't know is this version comes with the desktop.

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I would be virtualizing the linux install using UTM.